# Inlining JS ind EJS file after bundling with gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify, ejs

I am trying to get the output of a gulp-browserify combo as inline JS in a EJS template. The output needs to be a html file with inline JavaScript for reasons beyond my control.
I know browserify returns a stream so I tried playing around with the 'data' event but I cannot get the script tag filled with the actual code from the js file.

Index.ejs

```
<html>
<script><%= cscript %></script>
</html>
```

Index.js

```
console.log('this is a test');
```

Gulpfile

```
const ejs = require('gulp-ejs');

gulp.task('build:creative', () => {
    const js = browserify({
        entries: './src/creatives/index.js'
    }).transform('babelify').bundle()
        .on('data', (file) => {
                const jsText = file.toString();
            gulp.src('./src/creatives/index.ejs')
                .pipe(ejs({
                    cscript: jsText
                }))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/creatives'));
        });
});
```

Expected output:

```
<html>
    <script>console.log('this is a test');</script>
</html>
```

Actual output: Total Gibberish.

Does anybody have experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was able to figure it out. The answer lay in the node stream API. To achieve this, you need to concat the chunks during the `data` event and call the ejs method during the `end` event of the stream.

Gulpfile:

```
gulp.task('build:creative', () => {

    let jsString = '';
    browserify({
        entries: './src/creatives/index.js'
    })
    .transform('babelify')
    .bundle()
    .on('data', (file) => {
        jsString += file.toString();
    })
    .on('end', () => {
        gulp.src('./src/creatives/index.ejs')
            .pipe(ejs({
                cscript: jsString
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/creatives'));
    });
});
```

Index.ejs needed a slight adjustment as well to keep the JS string unescaped in the output.

```
<html>
<script><%- cscript %></script>
</html>
```